# undefined variable problem involving document.keydown () function

Tags: javascript, function, variables

Here's the problem, document.onkeydown = checkkeycode

I'm passing two variable to checkeycode e which is storing the event and hence keycode and the array circle which I want to update with variable c's latest position. when I pass circle to the function, it becomes undefined hence
{circle[4] = c._.ty};
returns an undefined error
I tried putting document.write(circle);
into the document and it just wrote undefined and when I switched it with E it became a keyboard object. What I need solved is:

1. how do I pass the array circle to the function so that when raphael translates the circle, it updates the values in circle?
2. in the if (keycode == blah ) do I just do {c.translate(value)} {circle[4] = c._.ty} ?
   do I append two different function to a single if event?

```
<html>  

<head>  

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/home/andrew/Documents/rahpael/raphael-min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<script language="javascript">

var paper = Raphael(50, 50, 420, 300);
var d = paper.rect(150, 150, 30, 30);
var c = paper.circle(50, 50, 40);
var circle = [c.attrs.cy, c.attrs.cx, c.attrs.r, c._.tx, c._.ty];
var rectie = [ d.attrs.x, d.attrs.y, d.attrs.height, d.attrs.width];

document.onkeydown = checkKeycode

function checkKeycode(e, circle) {
var keycode;
if (window.event) keycode = window.event.keyCode;  
else if (e) keycode = e.which;  
if (keycode == 40) { c.translate(0, 10)}; //{circle[4] = c._.ty};// down  
if (keycode == 39) { c.translate(10, 0)}; // right  
if (keycode == 38) { c.translate(0, -10)}; // up  
if (keycode == 37) { c.translate(-10, 0)}; // left  

}  
 // deleted some comments I've made so far.  

</script>  

</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Just saying: The `language`-attribute in the script-tag is deprecated. Better use `type="text/javascript"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of issues there:

1) Passing arguments

> I'm passing two variable to checkeycode

No, you aren't. The browser will pass *one* argument to it, the `event` (unless it's IE, but you've handled that).

If you change:

```
document.onkeydown = checkKeycode
```

to

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    checkKeycode(e, circle);
};
```

...you'll be passing in the `circle` you defined at global scope.

2) Names

Your `checkkeycode` function accepts the arguments `e` and `circle`, but appears to use `e` and `c` instead.

(Your `checkkeycode` code already closes over the `circle` at global scope anyway, so you could just drop the `circle` argument from the definition of `checkkeycode` and use `circle` rather than `c`. But best to keep things modular if you can, by passing the argument into the function.)

So if you're going modular and just closing over `circle` in the event handler:

```
var paper = Raphael(50, 50, 420, 300);
var d = paper.rect(150, 150, 30, 30);
var c = paper.circle(50, 50, 40);
var circle = [c.attrs.cy, c.attrs.cx, c.attrs.r, c._.tx, c._.ty];
var rectie = [ d.attrs.x, d.attrs.y, d.attrs.height, d.attrs.width];


document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    return checkKeycode(e, circle); // Event handler is closure over `circle`
};

//                       v-- `c`, not `circle`
function checkKeycode(e, c) {
    var keycode;
    if (window.event) keycode = window.event.keyCode;  
    else if (e) keycode = e.which;  
    if (keycode == 40) { c.translate(0, 10)}; //{circle[4] = c._.ty};// down  
    if (keycode == 39) { c.translate(10, 0)}; // right  
    if (keycode == 38) { c.translate(0, -10)}; // up  
    if (keycode == 37) { c.translate(-10, 0)}; // left  

}
```

Comment: thanks. I actually changed the function so I'm not sending circle into the function and just accessing it as a global variable and it's working. I didn't expect that. I tried to add it first and then mod it. I will try your suggestions though and thank you so much for the answer it really makes a difference to me.

Comment: @user: No problem. The reason the function has access to `circle` is that it's defined within the same scope as `circle` (global scope, in this case, but it's true if you define a function *within* another function as well). The JavaScript (and academic) term for this is *closure*; more here: ["Closures are not complicated"](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

Comment: @user: You're new to StackOverflow, so I'll mention: If you found this answer useful, click the up-arrow next to it -- that votes it up. If this answer *answers* the question (solves the problem, etc.), click the checkmark to the left of the beginning of the answer. That marks your question "answered" and credits this as the correct answer.